# Integrating Google Custom Search for ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, google-custom-search

I'm having the code for integrating Google Custom search into one of the ASP.Net websites. Google provided a script tag with an element to be placed on  the website as gcse:search

However, when I place the code in the body content warning displayed as shown in the screenshot
[snapshot with warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2olR.png). Ignoring the warning message, the content is not properly rendered (text entered remains invisible) as shown [snapshot from UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Noh8S.png).

When I place the same code in static html page, code works perfect.
Is there a way to include the element/tag as mentioned as a recognized namespace in asp.net web app & how? I cannot register that as a tag in asp.net since it's not a library.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the HTML5 compliant method described here:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5